# Get all inputs that are not followed by images using a jquery selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to make a selector that get's all the input elements that are not followed by an image with validation error.

Html:

```
<input id="target" type="submit" value="0" />
<input id="target1" type="submit" value="1" />
<input type="text" data-val="true" />
<input type="text" data-val="true" />
<input type="text" data-val="true" />
<input type="text" data-val="true" />
<input type="text" data-val="true" />
```

Jquery with iteration (works):

```
$("#target").click(function () {
    var errorTooltipIconURL = "xxx";
    $(document).find('[data-val="true"]').each(function () {
        if ($(this).next('.validation-error-tooltip-icon').length == 0) {
            $('<img src="' + errorTooltipIconURL + '" class="validation-error-tooltip-icon" style="visibility: hidden" />').insertAfter(this);
        }
    });
});
```

Jquery selector that I tried (doesn't insert after the last one, because it doesn't have another element after the last input):

```
$("#target1").click(function () {
    var errorTooltipIconURL = "xxx";
    $(document).find('[data-val="true"]+:not(.validation-error-tooltip-icon)').each(function () {
        $('<img src="' + errorTooltipIconURL + '" class="validation-error-tooltip-icon" style="visibility: hidden" />').insertBefore(this);    
    });
});
```

Here's a fiddle to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/TQMvh/1/

Answer (score 2):

The `+` selector requires a space between both sides of the selector. Also, you don't need `$(document).find`, you can simply do:

```
$('[data-val="true"] + :not(.validation-error-tooltip-icon)')
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TQMvh/3/)

Comment: If you have only input elements, it doesn't insert validation error after the last one. That was my problem also, + selector gives you the next element. But maybe there is no next element. If you remove the last image you will see it doesn't insert back another image.